# R dplyr's filter function won't work with renamed factor variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with the following structure:

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ type  : Factor w/ 4 levels "NON-ROAD","NONPOINT",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ year  : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1999"<"2002"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ sum.pm: num  522.9 240.8 248.9 55.8 2107.6 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol type
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

With this structure, I can select rows based on the year variable, e.g.,

```
reduced = filter(pm.baltimore.type, year == 1999)
```

However, if I change the variable names, i.e.,

```
new.var.names <- colnames(pm.baltimore.type)
new.var.names[1] <- "EmissionSource"
new.var.names[2] <- "Year"
new.var.names[3] <- "PM2.5"
colnames(pm.baltimore.type) <- new.var.names
```

giving me this structure:

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ EmissionSource: Factor w/ 4 levels "NON-ROAD","NONPOINT",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Year          : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1999"<"2002"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ PM2.5         : num  522.9 240.8 248.9 55.8 2107.6 ...
 - attr(*, "vars")=List of 1
  ..$ : symbol type
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

This fails:

```
reduced = filter(pm.baltimore.type, Year == 1999)
```

I get this error: Error: unknown column 'type'

Comment: What version of dplyr are you using (see `sessionInfo()`)? I can't reproduce this error. But it seems to be from changing the name of the grouping variable without re-specifying the new grouping variable.

Comment: Hi -- I'm using R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18). What do you mean by, or how do you, re-specify a new grouping variable? And why do you call Year, an ordered factor, a grouping variable ?

Comment: That's the R version, I'm more curious about the `dplyr` version you have installed. I tested with `dplyr_0.4.1 `. The class of your data object is first  `grouped_df` which means you probably ran `group_by()` at some point. If you don't want grouped, then you can use `ungroup()` on the data first.

Comment: I have dplyr Version: 0.4.2, dplyr_0.4.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [odd behavior with select in dplyr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728431/odd-behavior-with-select-in-dplyr)

Comment: I've voted to close this question not because it's of poor quality but because the problem and answer are addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728431/odd-behavior-with-select-in-dplyr